# How to read json file on disk using sails js api controller?

Tags: json, sails.js

I am new to sails js, I have to read json file in a sails generated controller and process the data in it. If its, express I generally use jsonfile module like this in app.js

```
let jsonfile = require('jsonfile')
let file = '/tmp/data.json'
jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
  console.dir(obj)
})
```

How to do the same in sails js controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, It seems as same as in express. I just tried able to read the data like this. In my controller

```
  module.exports = {

  readJsonFile: function (req, res) {

    const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
    var file = './assets/json/data.json';
    jsonfile.readFile(file, function (err, obj) {
      if (err) {
        res.json({err: err});
      }
      console.dir(obj)
      res.json({obj: obj});
    })
  }
};
```

and its working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `readFileSync` to read the JSON file

```
module.exports = {


  index: async function (req, res) {
    var filePath = './data/students.json';
    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
    sails.log("data", data);
    return res.view('pages/index.ejs', data);
  },


};
```